# Java: relocating element from index to front of linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while. When I run it against my test for relocating index 1, I get from `[A][B][C][D][E]` to `[B][B][C][D][E]`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public void moveToTop(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (index > size) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (index == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        Node ref = first;
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            ref = ref.next;
        }
        Node temp = null;
        temp = ref.next;
        ref = temp.next;
        temp = first;
        first = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void moveToTop(int index) {
    // index should go until size - 1, not size
    if (index >= size) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    // index == 0 should return the list unmodified
    if (index == 0) return;

    // We start in the head
    // first = A -> B -> C -> D -> E
    // ref = A -> B -> C -> D -> E
    Node ref = first; 
    for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
        // And loop until we find the node before the one we want to move
        // For index = 1, we won't loop, so ref is still equal to first
        ref = ref.next;
    }
    // temp = A.next => temp = B
    Node temp = ref.next;
    // ref (A) is the node before the one we wish to move
    // A.next = B.next => A.next = C => ref = A -> C -> D -> E
    ref.next = temp.next;
    // B.next = A => temp = B -> A -> C -> D -> E
    temp.next = first;
    // first = B -> A -> C -> D -> E
    first = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set the index in the loop to 0. 
With what you have there, its content won't be executed.

Secondly, look very closely at the assignment logic that follows. You need to assign the ref node to the temp variable, the ref to the first node, and then the temp to the ref.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this for loop instead:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        ref = ref.next;
 }
```